Next-auth JWT/Session Callbacks returns access_token but in getServerSession() token is undefined
Currently, I'm implementing authentication in my NextJS app with the next-auth package. I followed the documentation and created the /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js file which has the following configuration
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';

const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CognitoProvider({
            clientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_ISSUER,
        }), 
    ],
    session: {
      jwt: true,
    },
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
        if(account) {
          token.access_token = account.access_token;
        }
        return token;
      },
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        session.access_token = token.access_token;
        return session;
      },
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

I checked the output of the session callback and it returned the access_token as expected
In my Server or Client components I try to get the access_token with the getServerSession() and getSession() methods. Both returned undefined.
This is the code in one of my server components
    const session = await getServerSession();
    console.log(session.access_token);


Does someone know what the problem could be?
I already tried changing the route.js file from the [...nextauth]package with different configurations
